# "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing pdftotext: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, import, pdftotext

I got ImportError when importing *pdftotext* in studio code but not in anaconda
I also have the wheel files of *pdftotext* still it is not importing after installing successfully.

It only works in anaconda but not importing in studio code or idle.

The error message:

```
import pdftotext
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing *pdftotext*: The specified module could not be found.
```